# Get ReportSource parameters in custom ReportResolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-reporting

I currently try to create simple telerik report using asp .net mvc reporting, on Index.cshtml I have

```
@(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
        .Id("reportViewer1")
        .ServiceUrl(Url.Content("~/api/reports/"))
        .TemplateUrl(Url.Content("~/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.2.15.930.html"))
        .ReportSource(typeof(MyReport).AssemblyQualifiedName, new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"Id", 123} })
        .ViewMode(ViewMode.Interactive)
        .ScaleMode(ScaleMode.Specific)
        .Scale(1.0)
        .Deferred())
```

And also I сreated own ReportResolver

```
class ReportResolverWithFallBack : IReportResolver
{
    readonly IReportResolver parentResolver;

    public ReportResolverWithFallBack(IReportResolver parentResolver)
    {
        this.parentResolver = parentResolver;
    }

    public ReportSource Resolve(string report)
    {
        ReportSource reportDocument = null;
        reportDocument = this.CustomReportResolver(report);

        if (null == reportDocument && null != this.parentResolver)
        {
            reportDocument = this.parentResolver.Resolve(report);
        }

        return reportDocument;
    }

    public ReportSource CustomReportResolver(string report)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(report);
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        var reportInstance = (Report)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });

        InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new InstanceReportSource
        {
            ReportDocument = reportInstance
        };

        return instanceReportSource;
    }
}
```

How I can get specified parameters in ReportSource in Resolve method or maybe there is some other way, so I can get them in `NeedDataSource` event in `MyReport` class ?

Comment: Has there been any solution you've found to this issue? I need to use a custom resolver to change my connection string for the report, but now I'm no longer getting the parameters that were set in the mvc view.